# How to Crop / resize the image using Apex

Tags: apex, visualforce, images

I have a requirement to provide an interface for uploading an image with cropping and resize option. Once the image is cropped, I need to send this to the server.can we handle it through Apex Code.

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely not the sort Apex is designed to do and it's going to cause you more problems than it's worth—there is nothing in Apex (or any libraries) that will handle decoding of image file formats, let alone manipulation of data.

The best bet is to handle the image processing in Javascript inside a Visualforce page, and then send the resulting image data as a binary blob into a Salesforce document/attachment/whatever you're using.

[A quick search higlighted this list of Javascript utilities that might be of use](http://www.hotscripts.com/blog/javascript-image-cropping-scripts/).

If you're not planning on doing this through a UI then I'd have thought connecting to a webservice (either an existing one or something you cook up) that can make use of ImageMagick would be the next best option.

Comment: Looks like JavaScript UI to identify the crop area is one thing, but actually cropping the image in JavaScript is more problematic - see [Cropping images in the browser BEFORE the upload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12728188/cropping-images-in-the-browser-before-the-upload).

Comment: @KeithC Assuming you only care about modern browsers, you can draw to a canvas, manipulate it, and get the results into a file you can upload. I've done this with an drawing app in salesforce (captures digital signatures).